# Problem after connecting a usb gprs modem to ubuntu

Tags: drivers, usb-modem, 3g, huawei, ubuntu-drivers

I already have a Huawei 3G Usb Modem. Yesterday, I connected it to the computer and it was working fine with the internet but today, I detached it from my computer. Now, when I use Ctrl + Alt + F1, it always says:

```
login: [18.92] ata3: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4040000 action 0xe frozen
[18.93] ata3: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[21.13] ata3: SError { CommWake DevExch }
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I deactivate the driver of the 3G Usb Modem?